# Bash script command output error when splitting up and convert to int

Tags: java, bash, shell

I create a bash script to read the output from another command (`java -jar ...`).

The result from the command is like below:

```
MIN,MAX
6165350,6228865
```

I omit the first line using `head -2 | tail -1` so the output will become

```
6165350,6228865
```

And i save it to the variable called `output`

```bash
output=$(java -jar bundletool.jar get-size total --apks=$APKS_PATH | head -2 | tail -1)
```

Last, I create java file to split the output results

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] values = args[0].split(",");

        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(values[1]));
    }
}
```

And below is the final bash script

```bash
#!bin/bash
output=$(java -jar bundletool.jar get-size total --apks=$APKS_PATH | head -2 | tail -1)
java Demo $output
```

When i run the bash, why i'm getting the error

```
6165350
"xception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6228865
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
        at Demo.main(Demo.java:8)
```

I get the correct results when i try to change the `output`

```
output="6165350,6228865"
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked args with `System.out.println(args[0]);` ?

Comment: do those input lines have windows/dos line endings (`\r\n`)? the error message a) references the last number in the line (`6228865`) and b) appears to be missing the trailing double quote; (NOTE: I don't work with `java` so making a guess at this point ...) I'm wondering if a trailing `\r` would cause the trailing double quote to show up at the front of the string (ie, overprint the leading double quote)?  what is the output from running (`bash` command): `typeset -p output`?

Comment: Note: An easier way to omit the first line is with `sed 1d`. I agree that there is probably undesired whitespace that is causing problems. Printing the string length would help identify it as would printing the code points in hex, and a judicious use of `String::trim` would likely fix it.

Comment: ah, yeah, the trailing double quote is actually at the start of the line (see lambda-larry's answer) ... definitely an issue with a `\r` at the end of the line (ie, end of the 2nd number)

Comment: You can eliminate your second Java program and use other unix tools to split the output onto separate lines as another step in the pipeline - `sed` and `awk` immediately come to mind... for example `echo "$output" | head -2 | tail -1 | sed 's/,/\r\n/g'`

Comment: Thank you, I already checked the args[0] and printed without additional either `\r`or `\n`. I believe those characters exists in my args. And solved by using `trim()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a *[non-printing character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character)* there, typically the *[String#strip](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#strip())* method will remove it.
*[String#trim](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim())* may work, also.

Try the following.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] values = args[0].split(",");

    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(values[0].strip()));
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(values[1].strip()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked by using `.trim()` I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that there is a `\r` at the end of the last argument, which explains why `Exception` is spelled `"xception`.

You can confirm that it is the case by pipe the output to a hex dump.

```
java -jar bundletool.jar get-size total --apks=$APKS_PATH | head -2 | tail -1 | xxd
```

You can trim the `\r` of with `tr -d '\r'` in the bash part or strip the argument in the Java part.

```java
String[] values = args[0].strip().split(",");
```

Comment: Could also try `echo $output | od -xc`

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that your `bundletool.jar` produces a carriage return as line ending, I would (if you can not change the Java program to produce reasonable line endings) simply do a

```
nums=( $(java .... bundletool.jar ... |dos2unix|awk -F , '{print $1, $2}') )
```

You then have the first number in `${nums[0]}` and the second one in `${nums[1]}`